# My progressDialog doesn't roll?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to show a circle progressdialog when some functions run in backstage. so I write such a series of code:

```
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(GridLayoutActivity.this, "","...");
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        someFunc();
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);// 执行耗时的方法之后发送消给handler
    }
    }).start();
```

But the progressDialog doesn't roll? why?

Comment: why don't you use AsyncTask instead...

Comment: i use AsyncTask but get a worse effect ... could you teach me how to refresh ui use what you said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with Asynchronous task, here i post the example code, you may change as per you own

```
public class BackGround_Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                YourClassName.this);

        // can use UI thread here
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //Your Background Task

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            //What will you do after the completion of Background process

            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you tell me how to use this class in my own class?

Comment: Sure, First of all, Here for what purpose you are using Progress Bar?

Comment: @user1614589: What is your Actual task

Comment: I am sorry, and my task is to start a time consuming service

Comment: I check the document and use your class in this way:`BackGround_Task  o = new BackGround_Task ();o.execute();` and the progressdialog showed in a second ... that isn't what i want

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like this:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(GridLayoutActivity.this);
progressDialog.setMax(100);
progressDialog.setProgress(0);
progressDialog.setMessage("...");
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progressDialog.show();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    someFunc();
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);// 执行耗时的方法之后发送消给handler
}
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Send handler message after try block. Use like this:

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(SetFrames.this,"Loading", "Please Wait...",true);
           new Thread() {
               public void run() {
               try {
                 //your function
               }catch(Exception e)
               {
               }
               handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
               pd.dismiss();
               }

               }.start();

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        }
        };
```